# Unable to create simple archive

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

I'm trying to make a simple archive using the following makefile:

```
INC    :=-Ilibs/rapidxml-1.13

all: 
  $(CXX) -c $(INC) -o dove.o dove.hpp
  ar rvs libdove.a dove.o  
  ranlib libdove.a         

clean:
  rm -f dove.o libdove.a
```

the dove.hpp file has `#include "rapidxml.hpp"`, which you can see I point to a specific rapidxml at compile time. The `make all` target runs to completion, but 1) the output dove.o is massive (19MB!) when rapidxml+dove.hpp is only about 150K, and 2) neither the final libdove.a or the dove.o seem to be usable objects:

```
[hamiltont@4 dove]$ nm dove.o 
nm: dove.o: File format not recognized
[hamiltont@4 dove]$ nm libdove.a 
nm: dove.o: File format not recognized

[... in other project...]
[hamiltont@4 dove]$ g++ -o bin/AntHybrid build/*.o -L/home/hamiltont/foobar/dove -ldove
/home/hamiltont/foobar/dove/libdove.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, obvious mistake. I'm trying to compile a header file and then package that as a library. While precompiled headers [is possible](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html), there is really no need at all for a makefile in this directory